# Change the specific value of an array

Tags: php

I have an array and the data is fetched from a sql query. The array is saved in a variable called $users. Look:

```
<?php
    
    ...

    $data = array();
    $data['users'] = $users;
    $data['status']= true;
    $this->format_json($data);
    
?>
```

This is the result I get:

```
{
    "users":[
        {
            "id":"1",
            "name":"Joana",
            "avatar":"uploads/avatar/0eff31cdfa4d2b32c49e97dec010cc31_thumb.png"
        }
    ],
    "status":true
}
```

I would like to know how to add a link at the beginning of "avatar", for example:

```
{
    "users":[
        {
            "id":"1",
            "name":"Joana",
            "avatar":"https://sitename.com/uploads/avatar/0eff31cdfa4d2b32c49e97dec010cc31_thumb.png"
        }
    ],
    "status":true
}
```

I tried foreach, but I don't know how to use it correctly in this case. I don't know how to rewrite the $users array mentioned above.

Thank you, guys!

---

**Edit**

The problem was solved like this:

```
foreach ($users as $key => $entry) {
    $users[$key]->avatar = "https://sitename.com/" . $entry->avatar;
}
$data = array();
$data['users'] = $users;
$data['status']= true;
$this->format_json($data);
```

Comment: Please show your attempt. The context is important.

Comment: Something funky has gone on in your copy-paste. It's missing quotes.

Comment: This question is not about `sql`, so I removed that tag.

Comment: @Luuk, with few changes I solved the problem. Thanks you all!

Answer (score 0):

You can cycle through the array of users using a `foreach`. An `&` operator before `$value` will allow you to modify the array item directly without the need of an index.

```
foreach ( $data['users'] as &$value ) {
  $value['avatar'] = 'https://sitename.com/' . $value['avatar'];
}
```